# JS Summation of multiple inputs fields

Tags: javascript, php, function, input, html-table

I have the following Table `<th>` and `<td>` as follows :

```
Serial No.         Actual QTY            Input 1            Input 2
[  x1      ]        [ 5    ]             [      ]           [      ]
[  x2      ]        [ 9    ]             [      ]           [      ]
```

- note this `[    ]` indicates as input text field

JS Code :

```
function myFunction(v){
        var minus = v.value; 
        var original = v.getAttribute('data-original');
        var x = document.getElementById(v.getAttribute('data-goto'));
        x.value = original - minus;
        if(x.value < 0){
            alert('Actual QTY is Less than Zero!');
      }
    }
```

PHP Code :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['serial_no']."</td><td>";
    echo "<input class='original' type='text' id='c".$row['serial_no']."' value='".$row['qty']."' />";
    echo "</td>";
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
        echo "<td><input data-goto='c".$row['serial_no']."' data-original = '".$row['qty']."' onchange='myFunction(this);' type='text' name='n[]' /></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Based on the table above, I all I want is to sum `Input 1` and `Input 2` for each row and finds the remaining by subtracting the total of the two Inputs from the `Actual QTY` as follows:

```
Actual QTY = (Input 1 + Input 2) - Actual QTY
```

The PHP and JS code works only for 1 Input field at a time without summation of the two inputs, so When the user inserts a value in `Input 1`, it will decrements from the Actual QTY! But when inserting both on `Input 1` and `Input 2` the result will be false.

All I want is to find a way to relate both input fields together.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do a lot of this type of thing you may consider using a MVVM framework like knockout or kendo. They will help a lot when keeping related elements on a page in sync.

In this case I used jQuery since the others have some setup and would be overkill if this type of behavior is atypical of your application.

http://jsbin.com/tapoxoke/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Actual Qty</td>
    <th>Input 1</td>
    <th>Input 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="actual-qty">5</td>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><input/></td>
  </tr>    
<tr>
  <td class="actual-qty">7</td>
  <td><input/></td>
  <td><input/></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td class="actual-qty">3</td>
    <td><input/></td>
    <td><input/></td>
  </tr> 
</table>

<script>
$('input').on('change', function(e) {
   var $inputElement = $(e.target);
   $tableRow = $inputElement.closest('tr');
   $bothInputs = $tableRow.find('input');
   var actualQtyElement = $tableRow.find('.actual-qty')[0];

   var sumOfInputs = getSumOfInputs($bothInputs);
   var actual = getValueFromString(actualQtyElement.textContent);

   if(actual < sumOfInputs) {
     alert('Actual QTY is Less than Zero!');
   }
});


var getSumOfInputs = function($inputs) {
  var sum = 0;
  $inputs.each(function(index) {
    var input = $inputs[index];
    sum += getValueFromString(input.value);
  });
  return sum;
};

var getValueFromString = function(value) {
  value = parseInt(value);
  var isNan = Number.isNaN(value);
  return (isNan) ? 0 : value;
};
</script>
```